# Meaning of Error : Maximum number of duplicate updates in one batch (12 allowed)

Tags: apex, batch, governorlimits, duplicate-management

Lately I have came across an Error as given below.

**Maximum number of duplicate updates in one batch (12 allowed)**. Attempt to update Id more than once in this Api call

I was able to solve the issue by re-creating the file with unique values. But I want to know the exact meaning/reason for this error.
So My confusion is

When salesforce says that  ***Maximum number of duplicate updates in one batch (12 allowed)***  Does it mean that,

- its not allowed if I have 26 records in a file where I have 13 unique records and each one of them has 1 got duplicate
  records!?
- its not allowed if  I have 26 records in a file where 1 record is duplicated 13 times and rest of the 13 records in the file are unique.

Answer (score 3):

I got a similar error when I was creating test data for a Unit Test.  I tried inserting records who has a **Process Builder Flow** who updates their Parent's Field if a condition was met.  I had more than 12 children per parent in my `insert` which caused this error.

My message to Salesforce....WOW!  How silly!  Their **Process Builder** is **not** bulkified IMHO.  The Process Builder must run each record through the Process and collect any records for updating so it can do a bulk update at the end.  However, instead of storing records for updating as a `Map<Id, SObject>` (which would let the last Parent win), they store the records as a `SObject[]` (which is still last record wins) and just add records as they go.  Talk about asking for trouble.

An even better solution is to store records for update as `Map<Id, SObject>` and then as the Process Builder processes the batch, the Process Builder checks:

- If `records.get(record.Id) == null`, put the record in the Map.
- Then, for each Field to update: `records.get(record.Id).put(field, value)`

This would allow the last set Field per record to win (desirability is TBD).

Answer (score 0):

It is both

I did a test by exporting 21 Account records.

1. Copied the first one 13 times, got error on last 2 (14-2)

> Maximum number of duplicate updates in one batch (12 allowed)

2. Copied the 21 records and duplicate them, got errors on 9 of them (21-12)

> Maximum number of duplicate updates in one batch (12 allowed)

[SOAP Update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_update.htm)

> Fields whose names contain “Id” are either that object’s primary key
>   (see ID Field Type ) or a foreign key (see Reference Field Type).
>   Client applications cannot update primary keys, but they can update
>   foreign keys. For example, a client application can update the OwnerId
>   of an Account, because OwnerID is a foreign key that refers to the
>   user who owns the account record. Use describeSObjects() to confirm
>   whether the field can be updated.
>
> This call checks a batch for duplicate Id values, and if there are
>   duplicates, the first six are processed. For additional duplicate Id
>   values, the SaveResult for those entries is marked with an error
>   similar to the following: