# Why Is My fast update not Working if more than 12 records selected

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm Working on a flow that gets records (Time_Card__c) if their Invoice field is null. It then populates a Record Collection variable and does a fast update. If I select 12  or less records it works If I select more it fails. At some point I would like to remove the selection process and update all within a date range which will return more than 12 records. Here is part of the Debug that Passes.

```
ASSIGNMENT: Assign_to_Records
{!vlIndivitualNULLTimeCard.Invoice__c} Equals {!vInvoice}
Result
{!vlIndivitualNULLTimeCard.Invoice__c} = "a3SW0000000FDuFMAW"

ASSIGNMENT: Add_To_Collection_Variables
{!vFinalTimeCardupdate} Add {!vlIndivitualNULLTimeCard}
Result
{!vFinalTimeCardupdate} = "[Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNIsMAM),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNHzMAM),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNIiMAM),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNIjMAM),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNGCMA2),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNI4MAM),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNJ2MAM),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNIJMA2),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNITMA2),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNGRMA2)]"
LOOP: Loop_through_TimeCards
End Loop.

FAST UPDATE: UpdateRecords
Update Time_Card__c records whose IDs are stored in {!vFinalTimeCardupdate}.
Variable Values
[Id=a2UW0000000dNIsMAM,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNHzMAM,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNIiMAM,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNIjMAM,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNGCMA2,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNI4MAM,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNJ2MAM,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNIJMA2,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNITMA2,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNGRMA2,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
Result
All records whose IDs are in {!vFinalTimeCardupdate} are ready to be updated when the next Screen or Wait element is executed or when the interview finishes.
```

The Follwoing is the filure:

```
{!vlIndivitualNULLTimeCard.Invoice__c} Equals {!vInvoice}
Result
{!vlIndivitualNULLTimeCard.Invoice__c} = "a3SW0000000FDuFMAW"

ASSIGNMENT: Add_To_Collection_Variables
{!vFinalTimeCardupdate} Add {!vlIndivitualNULLTimeCard}
Result
{!vFinalTimeCardupdate} = "[Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNHuMAM),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNIEMA2),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNIdMAM),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNIxMAM),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNInMAM),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNIOMA2),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNJ7MAM),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNG7MAM),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNI9MAM),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNIYMA2),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNIsMAM),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNHzMAM),Time_Card__c (a2UW0000000dNIiMAM)]"
LOOP: Loop_through_TimeCards

End Loop.

FAST UPDATE: UpdateRecords
Update Time_Card__c records whose IDs are stored in {!vFinalTimeCardupdate}.
Variable Values
[Id=a2UW0000000dNHuMAM,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNIEMA2,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNIdMAM,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNIxMAM,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNInMAM,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNIOMA2,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNJ7MAM,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNG7MAM,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNI9MAM,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNIYMA2,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNIsMAM,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNHzMAM,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
[Id=a2UW0000000dNIiMAM,Invoice__c=a3SW0000000FDuFMAW]
Result
Failed to update records whose IDs are in {!vFinalTimeCardupdate}.
Error Occurred: The flow tried to update these records: null. This error occurred: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER: We can't save this record because the “Update invoice from Timecard” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow
An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow. Please contact your system administrator for more information. Error ID: 2144499856-24745 (1573568561). You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.---The flow tried to update these records: null.
```

[image]

I am New to flows and assume this is a rookie mistake. Inadvance. thank you for your time

Comment: any chance there is a downstream PB or flow that attempts to update the same record more than 12 times (violating a SFDC restriction)?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I shut off one PB but Not the other.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The number '12' is a good clue that your Visual Flow or Process Builder is running up against the SFDC limit on how many times a record can be updated (which is 12)

References:

- [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EAVDQA4&title=process-fails-if-it-attempts-to-update-a-single-record-more-than-12-times-in-a-single-transaction)
- [Maximum Number of Duplicate Errors in one batch (SFSE)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174330/meaning-of-error-maximum-number-of-duplicate-updates-in-one-batch-12-allowed)

This can happen when you have, for example, a Process Builder that attempts to update the same parent record for a batch of children within the action group.

Check your org to see if you have parallel or downstream PBs or Flows that were not designed properly